# GKSession sendDataToAllPeers getting invalid parameter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, bluetooth, gamekit

This is my first post and I wanted to start it by thanking the many stackoverflow contributors who will never know how much they helped me out these past several days as I worked to complete my first iOS app. I am indebted to them and to this site for giving them a place to post. To 'pay off' some of that debt, I hope this will help others as I have been helped...

So, my app uses the GKPeerPickerController to make a connection to a 2nd device. Once connected, the devices can send text messages to each other. The receiving peer has the message displayed in a UIAlertView. Everything was working fine.

Then I decided to experiment with locations and added code to get the current location. I convert it into latitude & longitude in degrees, minutes, and seconds and put them into one NSString.  I added a button to my storyboard called 'Send Location' which, when tapped, sends the location to the connected peer. This is where I ran into the problem.

btnSendLocation calls sendPacket with a NSString. sendPacket converts the string to NSData and calls sendDataToAllPeers, which was failing. When I learned how to capture the error, it was "Invalid parameter for - sendDataToAllPeers:withDataMode:error:". Why is the error occurring? I have two other methods that also call sendPacket and work fine.

```
    -(IBAction)btnSendLocation: (id)sender
    {
// Put latitude, longitude into string, then convert to NSData for sending
NSMutableString *tmp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Latitude: "];
// Build the location string to send
[tmp appendString:slatitude];
    // …code for longitude
strToSend = [tmp copy];
bool sentPkt = false;
sentPkt = [self sendPacket:strToSend  failedWithError:nil];
}

    - (bool)sendPacket: (NSString *)strToSend failedWithError: (NSError *)error
{
bool sendPktOK = false;
packet = [strToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
// Send the packet.
sendPktOK = [self.currentSession sendDataToAllPeers:packet 
                       withDataMode:GKSendDataReliable error:&error];
// If there was an error, log it.
if (!sendPktOK) {
    NSLog(@"Error Domain: %@", [error domain]);
    NSLog(@"Error Descr: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    NSLog(@"Error Code: %@", [error code]);
    return NO;
}    
return YES;
}

    - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
//  Location default is decimal degrees notation; convert to deg-min-secs
    int degrees = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    double decimalPart = fabs(newLocation.coordinate.latitude - degrees);
    int minutes = decimalPart * 60;
    double seconds = decimalPart * 3600 - minutes * 60;
    NSString slatitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d° %d' %1.1f\"",
                  degrees, minutes, seconds];
 // rest of code...
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  It's great that you solved your problem.  You should post the answer *as* an answer to this question, then mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do some more testing and found the answer. The issue was not in sendDataToAllPeers, it was in the conversion of the NSString (strToSend) to NSData:

```
packet = [strToSend dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Specifically, it was the degree sign character (little circle, ASCII 176). NSASCIIStringEncoding only includes ASCII characters up to 127, which is confirmed in a comment in NSString.h  (Foundation.framework). I'm sure there was a quicker way to find the problem, but I don't know Objective-C or Xcode's debugging facility well enough yet.